# Highsoft Highcharts not visible inside asp.net mvc partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I try to render a highsoft highchart inside a partial view.
If I render the chart on a main view, everthing works fine.

The partial view will be loaded via an ajax call inside my main view "index.cshtml":

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<button id="showIndexChart" onclick="RenderIndexPartial()">Get Partial</button>

<div id="PartialContent">

</div>



@section scripts{
    <script>

        var RenderIndexPartial = function () {
           $.ajax({
                url: '/Line/RenderIndexPartial',
                type: "Get",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (PartialViewData) {
                    $('#PartialContent').html(PartialViewData);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log("status: " + status + " / error: " + error);
                },
            });
        };

    </script>
}
```

The controller action for the partial view looks like this:
It returns the partial view and a model (object Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Highcharts)

```
      [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RenderPartial()
        {
            List<double> tokyoValues = new List<double> { 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6 };
            List<LineSeriesData> tokyoData = new List<LineSeriesData>();

            tokyoValues.ForEach(p => tokyoData.Add(new LineSeriesData { Y = p }));


            var tmpChart = new Highcharts()
            {
                Chart = new Chart
                {
                    Height = 100,
                    Width = 100,
                    Type = ChartType.Line,
                    RenderTo = "containerPartial",
                },
                Title = new Title
                {
                    Text = "Monthly Average Temperature",
                },
                XAxis = new List<XAxis>
                {
                    new XAxis
                    {
                        Categories = new List<string> { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                                    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" },

                    }
                },
                YAxis = new List<YAxis>
                {
                    new YAxis
                    {
                        Title = new YAxisTitle
                        {
                            Text = "Temperature (°C)"
                        },
                        PlotLines = new List<YAxisPlotLines>
                        {
                                new YAxisPlotLines
                            {
                                Value = 0,
                                Width = 1,
                                Color = "#808080"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                Series = new List<Series>
                {
                    new LineSeries
                    {
                        Name = "Tokyo",
                        Data = tokyoData,
                    },

                }
            };

            return PartialView("_Index", tmpChart);
        }
```

The partial view "_index.cshtml" is here:

```
@model Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Highcharts

@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts

<h1>Partial loaded</h1>

<div id="containerPartial" style="height: 400px">

    @(Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(Model, "ChartB")

</div>
```

If I check the dom elements there is somthing missing inside the highcharts div

[image]

Can maybe someone help me? Thank you so much.

Update:
The div content an my main view where the chart is visible looks a little bit dirrent:

[image]

And thats the response from my ajax call what shoul load to the div "PartialContent":

```
<h1>Partial loaded</h1>

<div id="containerPartial" style="height: 400px">

    <div id='ChartB' style='height:100;min-width:100;clear:both;margin: 0 auto;'></div><script type='text/javascript'>if (document.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {createChartChartB();});} else if (document.attachEvent) {document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){if (document.readyState === "complete"){document.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", arguments.callee);createChartChartB();}});}function createChartChartB() {var ChartOptions = {"xAxis":[{"categories":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]}],"chart":{"height":100,"width":100,"type":"line","renderTo":"ChartB"},"title":{"text":"Monthly Average Temperature"},"series":[{"name":"Tokyo","type":"line","data":[{"y":7},{"y":6.9},{"y":9.5},{"y":14.5},{"y":18.2},{"y":21.5},{"y":25.2},{"y":26.5},{"y":23.3},{"y":18.3},{"y":13.9},{"y":9.6}]}],"yAxis":[{"title":{"text":"Temperature (°C)"},"plotLines":[{"width":1,"color":"#808080","value":0}]}]};new Highcharts.chart("ChartB",ChartOptions);}</script>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Osti, Any errors in the console? The generated JS code seems to look ok, but are you sure that the code is called? Could you check that, for example by inserting some `console.log`?

Comment: I added another picture to my question and the consolge.log(PartialViewData)

Comment: Hi @Osti, All these elements in the chart container are created by `chart` constructor function. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kfv2dupt/ - your code works correctly. However, I think that the problem is caused by the events. Please try to call `createChartChartB()` without if - else statemants.

Comment: OK, but my whole chart will be created at the controller side and passed as model inside my partial view. How should I remove the "if else" statement?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know `ASP.NET`, I can help you only with JS code. It seems that your JS code is not called because it is loaded asynchronously and `DOMContentLoaded` event was already called. Similar case: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dozb7rgq/

Comment: I changed the ajax succecc from:
$('#PartialContent').html(PartialViewData);

to:

$('#PartialContent').html(PartialViewData);
createChartChartB();

The chart will be visible now. But in this case I need to now the name of the function "createChartChartB()".
At the end I will have about 15 charts inside my partial view. So I need 15 function calls.

Comment: Or is there a way to set a specific functin name instead of createChartChartB()?